# Search is not returning array elements if its not matching with its case

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, typescript

I have a code snippet in below which searches for array elements which matches the given string.

Its working as expected but its returning only if i'm giving text with same case.

for eg. given text is "Sa" it returning elements which has only "Sa" not "sa" and "SA" i want it to return all array elements which matches with the string irrespective of case.

**It should return all the three elements even if i give "sa" or "SA"**

```
var k = [{name:"Sameer"},{name:"salman"},{name:"SAHIL"}];

k = k.filter(s =>{
  return ~s.name.indexOf("S");
});

console.log(k)
```

[Link to JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62ahufxg/)

Comment: you can use either name.toLowerCase() or name.toUpperCase accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
 k = k.filter(name => name.toLowerCase().indexOf("s") === 0);
```

Just unify the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `toUpperCase()` if you are using a uppercase character or `toLowerCase()` if you are using lower case character. Rest, everything from your code works fine.

```js
var k = [{name:"Sameer"},{name:"salman"},{name:"SAHIL"}];

k = k.filter(s =>{
  return ~s.name.toUpperCase().indexOf("S");
});

console.log(k)
```

When you have single statement inside `fiter` you can omit the `return` like this.

```js
var k = [{name:"Sameer"},{name:"salman"},{name:"SAHIL"}];

k = k.filter(s => ~s.name.toUpperCase().indexOf("S"));

console.log(k)
```

Comment: Not returning if searching with lower case

Comment: Can you post how you are searching it with lowercase in the comment

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `toUpperCase` to `name` key and then check for `indexOf` like

```js
// Update with lowercase or uppercase string here
var searchString = 's';  

var k = [{name:"Sameer"},{name:"salman"},{name:"SAHIL"}];

k = k.filter(({name}) => ~name.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase()));

console.log(k)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var k = [{name:"Sameer"},{name:"salman"},{name:"SAHIL"}];

k = k.filter(s =>{
   return ~(s.name.toLowerCase()).indexOf("s");
});

console.log(k);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use str.includes() for this. Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp . 
As I know str.indexOf() use to a specific character or string.